# How can I change the string data type to int massively in Mongodb?

Tags: json, mongodb, nosql

I have a database something like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("61b69c02f92253fbe1017f23"),
        "nombre" : "Judd",
        "primer_apellido" : "Saterthwait",
        "segundo_apellido" : "Wabb",
        "identificacion" : "929499610",
        "genero" : "M",
        "edad" : "22",
        "seguridad_social" : "0",
        "telefono" : "4796610146",
        "banco" : "BANK OF AMERICA",
        "cuenta" : "36687045607282",
        "ciudad" : "Lihu",
        "desarrollador" : "senior",
        "trabaja_en" : "Thoughtsphere",
        "correo" : "jwabb3j@admin.ch",
        "pass" : "aea6d8bed55166ecde96d8ca1c687234",
        "fec_ultimo_acceso" : "2021-04-30",
        "tiene_hijos" : "1",
        "carnetizado" : "0",
        "activo" : "0",
        "reportes" : "1"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("61b69c02f92253fbe1017f39"),
        "nombre" : "Alleyn",
        "primer_apellido" : "Corneljes",
        "segundo_apellido" : "Andrivel",
        "identificacion" : "615842724",
        "genero" : "M",
        "edad" : "46",
        "telefono" : "6722395057",
        "banco" : "CITYBANK",
        "cuenta" : "4508531326650291",
        "ciudad" : "Sambonggede",
        "desarrollador" : "senior",
        "trabaja_en" : "Skyndu",
        "correo" : "aandrivelat@wix.com",
        "pass" : "a16ebf90ff6d116d220db8ede95ae253",
        "fec_ultimo_acceso" : "2021-04-30",
        "tiene_hijos" : "1",
        "carnetizado" : "1",
        "activo" : "0",
        "reportes" : "2"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("61b69c02f92253fbe1017f75"),
        "nombre" : "Tessa",
        "primer_apellido" : "Biesinger",
        "segundo_apellido" : "De Meis",
        "identificacion" : "12958583",
        "genero" : "F",
        "edad" : "50",
        "seguridad_social" : "1",
        "telefono" : "7465255759",
        "banco" : "GM2",
        "cuenta" : "6709265650990708",
        "ciudad" : "Wuyang",
        "desarrollador" : "junior",
        "trabaja_en" : "Babbleset",
        "correo" : "tdemeis7s@wired.com",
        "pass" : "0f4e5cee2132609be62102ab945c723a",
        "fec_ultimo_acceso" : "2021-04-30",
        "tiene_hijos" : "1",
        "carnetizado" : "0",
        "activo" : "1",
        "reportes" : "2"
}
```

What happens is that in the 'edad' key (age in english), it is as a number but in string, for example: "45". I want to change the data type from string "45" to number 45, of all the objects stored in the database. How can I do it? (I think it is with forEach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query

- pipeline update requires MongoDB >= 4.2
- change the age field from string to integer, to all documents ({} matches to all), using the `$toInt` aggregate operator.
- use `updateMany` method of your driver or set option  `{"multi" : true}`
  to update all the documents.

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70329485-m)

```js
update({},[{"$set": {"edad": {"$toInt": "$edad"}}}],{"multi" : true})
```

Comment: thank u very much<3